# How do i pull lightuserdata from my lua CFunctions from lua5.1 (luajit)?

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to have lua touch my C++ side code directly. I essentially want a runtime controller that would be unlikely to do any needless copies or add unwanted performance overhead

Right now I'm having difficulty doing that because i cant seem to pull the pointer that i provided beforehand... Would appreciate some guidance to get this working...

```
#include <luajit-2.0/lua.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

static int vpop (lua_State *L)
{
    std::vector<int> * ptr =  (std::vector<int> * )lua_touserdata(L,1); // im expecting to vec's address from main(), but alas, i get null
    std::cout << "pop ptr:" << ptr << "\n";

  return 0;
}

static int vpush (lua_State *L)
{
    std::vector<int> * ptr = (std::vector<int> * )lua_touserdata(L,1);
    std::cout << "push ptr:" << ptr << "\n";  return 1;
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec {0,1,2,3,4,5};
lua_State * L = lua_open();
luaL_openlibs(L);
static const luaL_reg Foo_methods[] = {
  {"vpop", vpop},
  {"vpush", vpush},
  {NULL,NULL}
};

luaL_register(L,"arr",Foo_methods);


lua_pushlightuserdata(L,&vec); // sending the address of the vector


if (luaL_dostring(L,"arr.vpop();"))
{
    printf("%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
}



return 0;    

}
```

this is the stdout

> pop ptr:0

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing any data to `arr.vpop()`. What would you expect from the code?:

```
arr.vpop()
```

Whatever you push before calling `luaL_dostring()` is not used at all, because `luaL_dostring()` is defined as:

> (luaL_loadstring(L, str) || lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0))

See arguments to `lua_pcall()`. Zero arguments will be used.

And even if you call `lua_pcall()` with adjusted arguments, your Lua code still doesn't pass any arguments to `arr.vpop()`. At least you should be passing through chunk's arguments using vararg expression:

```
arr.vpop(...)
```